# Oracle setup on Mac with VM Port Forwarding Problems

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea, virtualbox, oracle-sqldeveloper, portforwarding

I'm facing strange issues with regards to port forwarding an oracle port (1521) from localhost (127.0.0.1) to an Oracle Linux VM (10.0.2.15) I've setup on VirtualBox on my Macbook Pro.

Below is a screenshot of the vm network setting

[image: NAT Settings]

Below is the screenshot of port forwarding rules for the vm network setting

[image: Port Forwarding Setting]

- Telnet on the port works without any issues
- Firewall is disabled both on the guest and the host

However, if I try to connect to the oracle instance using SQL Developer or IntelliJ IDE, I get an invariable "IO Error" as below

[image: SQL Developer Test]

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved by reimporting the Oracle OS on the VirtualBox

Everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop iptables in your db box. Just run 'sudo service iptables stop'.